# Is there any way or need to empty your bowels before excercise?

Tags: food, exercise

I try to not take large meals for at least 12 hours before starting, yet abdominal exercises still can make me feel unwell and go to bathroom.

Is it normal? Or should I reconsider my diet? Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: There's nothing worse than needing a crap half way through a long run

Comment: @ChrisS actually crapping yourself would be worse, no?

Comment: @RyanMiller [Ask him](http://livenlovecestlavie.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/runner-diarrhea.jpg) (not for the squeamish).

Answer (score 8):

You should not need to empty your bowels prior to exercise. If you are experiencing discomfort during abdominal exercise, you should make sure your diet:

- contains enough fiber to allow you to go regularly

  - [The Mayo Clinic has a nice list of high-fiber foods](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/high-fiber-foods/NU00582)
- you are not taking excessive [diuretics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diuretics)
- you are not taking in foods that cause excess gas or bloating

  - [About.com has a list of foods known to cause excess gas and bloating](http://ibs.about.com/od/ibsfood/a/GassyFoods.htm)

If you are following all of those rules and still experiencing this problem regularly, then you should consider talking to your doctor about it.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any resources classifying foods regarding 1 or 3?

Comment: @Nikita Rybak - I added some resources for you.

Comment: +1 for 'not taking excessive diuretics'. It gets tiring to see all the reports on TV about the "health benefits of drinking coffee" when they glaze over the fact that it's a diuretic and many people walk around feeling like crap all the time because they're chronically dehydrated. Not to mention that their breath smells like something that died when they talk to you.

Answer (score 3):

My strategy for really intense workouts (ie long distance running) -- drink lots of water and eat some carbs (ie granola bars) before starting. Relax for a half hour or so while you hydrate and much lightly. I find this helps my bowels to move so I won't have to go while running. This consistently works for me, if this doesn't make me have to go, nothing will.